# Deleting some elements from a Python dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary and a list. I want to delete from the dictionary those values which appear in the list (if these values are presented in the dictionary). These elements can appear in the dictionary many times.

For example:
`my_dic={'key1':['a','b','c'],'key5':['d','a','e']}`.
I want to delete the values 'a' and 'c' without calling keys (key1 and key5).

How can I proceed?

Comment: What does it mean for something to be present in a dictionary? Dictionaries are key-value mappings, not simple containers; it's not clear whether you're looking at keys, or values, or what.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I refer to values. The keys aren't useful at this step for me, but I want to keep them, for the future steps.

Comment: Can you provide me the reasons for which you downvote this question?

Comment: I've edited the question and I said that I refer to values. It was unclear. Now I'm giving you the example.

Comment: Like you see, there are users who understood my question and they help me.

Comment: @CiprianVintea, I would not have bothered with the answer - if I was not so dissatisfied with the initial answer you got. Forum etiquette requires showing some effort before asking questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this i think

```
lst = ['val1','val2','val3']
dct = {
   'key1': ['val1','val6'],
   'key2': ['val2','val45'],
   'key3': ['val52','val48']
}

for key in dct.keys():
    vals = dct[key]
    for value in vals:
        if value in lst:
            while value in vals:
                 vals.remove(value)
    dct[key] = vals


print dct >>> {'key3': ('val52', 'val48'), 'key2': ('val45',), 'key1': ('val6',)}
```

Comment: And if a value appears more than once in *vals*?

Comment: A value can appear only once in vals. It can appear in more vals list

Comment: Did you notice that _while_ makes _if_ redundant?

Comment: You can remove the while loop so it will look through the list only once

Comment: Anyway this answer was modified, I didn't copied and pasted this code, but the idea was good for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
target_dict = {'key1':['a','b','c'],'key5':['d','a','e']}
values_to_detele = ['a', 'c']
In [225]: for val_list in target_dict.itervalues():
    for del_val in  values_to_detele:
        while del_val in val_list:
            val_list.remove(del_val)
   .....:             

In [226]: target_dict
Out[226]: {'key1': ['b'], 'key5': ['d', 'e']}
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'itervalues'

Comment: If you use Python 3 use `values` instead.